# i18next: case-insensitive keys

Tags: javascript, translation, i18next

How to say [i18next](https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18next) to match keys **case-insensitively**?

---

For example, when I have this in my translation file:

```json
  "My Name": "نام من",
```

I want it works for **`t('my name')`** *(in addition to `t('My Name')`)*.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.
A key is unique, so the only way to do so is also having that key lowercase in the resources.